# Does there exist a number $n >1$ such that $n = s(n)^{s(n)}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Let $s(n) = \text{the sum of digits of $n$}$, here I'm interested in a number $n>1$, such that $n=s(n)^{s(n)}$. With $1$ we clearly get the trivial solution $1=1^1$. Now the big question: Is there a number greater than $1$ with this property? I made a little observation:

- $1=1^1$ (trivial solution)
- $2\ne2^2$
- $3\ne3^3$
- $10\ne 1^1$
- $11\ne 2^2$
- $12\ne 3^3$
- $100\ne1^1$
- $199\ne19^{19}$
- $9999\ne36^{36}$

As you can see,  numbers on the right side become very large compared with numbers on the left side if $n$ has large digits. So I think if an $n>1$ with this property exists, then $n$ must be a (very) large number and must contain a lot of zeros (or ones ?) in its digits. So does there exist number $n>1$ with this property?

Comment: Take log of both sides. Bound s(n) based on number of digits.

Comment: If there is such a number, then there is a number $s>1$, such that the digit sum of $s^s$ is equal to $s$. In the range [2,10^4], no such $s$ exists.

Comment: It is hard to bound $s(n)$ because for any $n$ even very large these inequalities are tight : $n \geq s(n) \geq 1$.

Comment: $\;\displaystyle n=s(n)^{s(n)}$ may be solved as $\;\displaystyle s(n)=e^{W(\ln(n))}\;$ using $\,W(x\ln(x))=\ln(x)\,$ with $W$ the [LambertW function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Identities) and $x=s(n)$. But you seem to insist on $s(n)$ integer so...

Comment: @Zubzub: How can $n\ge s(n)$ be tight for $n\ge 10$?

Comment: @celtschk Yes you're right. Also I think the upperbound is not that useful because it would only tell us to look for some $n$ larger than a constant which is a big subset of number :-P

Comment: If $s$ is a power of $10$, the digitsum of $s^s$ is $1$. It $s>10$ is not a power of $10$, it seems that $\frac{digitsum(s^s)}{s}$ is always greater than $2$, except in the case $s=2\cdot 10^k$, for which the fraction is about $1.3$ and seems to converge to some number near $1.35$. But I have no idea how to prove this.

Comment: If you replace $s$ with the sum of digits in another base, then there are cases where such a number exists, for example bases 3, 5 and 9.

Comment: To make the numbers more manageable, I think we should consider $s(n)=s\left(s(n)^{s(n)}\right)$

Comment: I had Mathematica look for numbers $x$ such that $x=s(x^x)$ - which is equivalent to having $n=x^x$ be a solution to your problem. It turned up no results for $s(n)\leq 10^4$ other than $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

I considered the prime factorization. Since n and s(n) must consist of same selection of primes, we must focus on numbers having small number of prime divisors with large powers. For example if we pick 2 and 3, our number n must at least (2.3)^6 since sum of digits (if it can) is at least 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

In binary, there exists an n > 1 with the aforementioned property: the number 46656 (1011011001000000 in binary) appears to work.

Comment: I do think this is an answer, but a bad one. From the context of the question, it is clear that the OP is talking about digits in base-10 representation.